# How to execute Access query in C# like stored procedure

Tags: c#, oledb, ms-access-2013, oledbcommand

I am trying to execute MS Access query with parameters, and always got an error, that 1 more parameter is required.
Here is my query

```
PARAMETERS RendszamParam Text ( 255 );
SELECT *
FROM Auto
WHERE Rendszam=[RendszamParam];
```

The method that calls the query:

```
public Auto RendszamAlapjan (string rendszam)
{
     Auto auto = null;

     using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(KapcsolatAdatai.KapcsolatiString))
     {
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

       command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       command.CommandText = "AtoRendszamAlapjan";
       command.Parameters.Add("@RendszamParam", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rendszam;
       //command.Parameters.Add("@RendszamParam", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rendszam;

        connection.Open();

        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              auto = MapEntiy(reader);
           }
        }
     }

     return auto;
  }

private Auto MapEntiy(OleDbDataReader data)
{
     Auto auto = new Auto
     {
        Rendszam = data["rendszam"].ToString(),
        Tipus = data["tipus"].ToString(),
        Kategoria = data["kategoria"].ToString(),
        UtasokSzama = int.Parse(data["utasok_szama"].ToString()),
        AjtokSzama = int.Parse(data["ajtok_szama"].ToString()),
        Tempomat = bool.Parse(data["tempomat"].ToString()),
        BerletiDij = double.Parse(data["berleti_dij"].ToString())
     };

     return auto;
}
```

In **RendszamAlapjan** if I double the parameters (the commented line) it works fine, but without it I got an error message that one more parameter is required, and I can't figure it out why.

Comment: Not sure in access, but in sql server I would `command.CommandText = "AtoRendszamAlapjan"` and also  `WHERE Rendszam=@RendszamParam`

Comment: Edited the questin, I misstyped it in my query, but cant check now will it work.

Comment: Should work, the problem is that you should either pass the parameter to the exec instruction `CommandText = "EXEC AtoRendszamAlapjan @RendszamParam"` or keep it simple and just use the stored procedure name `CommandText = "AtoRendszamAlapjan"`

Comment: CommandText = "EXEC AtoRendszamAlapjan @RendszamParam" is not working, neather when I changed my misstype RendszamParam as @RendszamParam

Comment: Check the [microsoft forums example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a36243ad-705a-4e35-83d5-0bcf6c33bc66/parameter-pass-to-access-stored-procedure-from-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Tried, and it as I can see not the query is not executed. I think now that is  a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

In the query we dont have to specify parametars, just use @sing in query and Accsess 2013 will automaticly recognize that's a variable (parameter), like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Auto
WHERE Rendszam=[@RendszamParam];
```

And the calling method looks like this:

```
public Auto RendszamAlapjan (string rendszam)
      {
         Auto auto = null;

         using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(KapcsolatAdatai.KapcsolatiString))
         {
            OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "AtoRendszamAlapjan";
            command.Parameters.Add("@RendszamParam", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rendszam;

            connection.Open();

            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                  auto = MapEntiy(reader);
               }
            }
         }

         return auto;
      }
```

Hope helped someone.